# Deserializing JSON with dynamic keys

Tags: c#, json, dynamic, deserialization

I'm quite new to JSON, and am currently learning about (de)serialization.
I'm retrieving a JSON string from a webpage and trying to deserialize it into an object. Problem is, the root json key is static, but the underlying keys are dynamic and I cannot anticipate them to deserialize. Here is a mini example of the string :

```
{
    "daily": {
        "1337990400000": 443447,
        "1338076800000": 444693,
        "1338163200000": 452282,
        "1338249600000": 462189,
        "1338336000000": 466626
    }
}
```

For another JSON string in my application, I was using a `JavascriptSerializer` and anticipating the keys using class structure. What's the best way to go about deserializing this string into an object?

Comment: how about "expecting" a Dictionary<string,string>?

Comment: It'd be great if you could post an example of that as an answer :)

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Seriously, no need to go down the dynamic route; use

```
var deser = new JavaScriptSerializer()
    .Deserialize<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>>(val);
var justDaily = deser["daily"];
```

to get a dictionary, and then you can e.g.

```
foreach (string key in justDaily.Keys)
    Console.WriteLine(key + ": " + justDaily[key]);
```

to get the keys present and the corresponding values.

Answer (score 6):

Whenever you have JSON with dynamic keys it can usually be deserialized into a `Dictionary<string, SomeObject>`.  Since the inner JSON keys are dynamic (in this question) the JSON can be modelled as:

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>
```

I would recommend using [NewtonSoft.Json](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Introduction.htm) (JSON.Net) or [System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json?view=netcore-3.1) (if you're working in .NET-Core 3.0 and up).

**Newtonsoft.Json**

Use `DeserializeObject<T>` from `JsonConvert`:

```
var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>>(json);
```

**System.Text.Json**

Use `Deserialize<T>` from `JsonSerializer`:

```
var response = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>>(json);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `dynamic` in .NET 4 or later. For example with JSON.NET I can do:

```
dynamic obj = JsonConvert.Deserialize<dynamic>("{x: 'hello'}");
```

You can then do:

```
var str = obj.x;
```

However, unsure how it will handle numeric keys. You can of course just use `JObject` directly itself, for example:

```
var obj = JObject.Parse("{'123456': 'help'}");
var str = obj["123456"];
```

Comment: If he doesn't know what the keys will be, can you get an "all keys" collection out of the dynamic?

Comment: Probably using reflection yes (wouldn't be pretty). I much prefer using JObject as it basically shrink wraps a dictionary of sorts.

Answer (score -2):

This is not convenient to use, because in с# can not be defined a variable starts with a number. Add prefix to keys.

Or try this:

```
string json = "
{ daily:[
  { key: '1337990400000', val:443447 },
  { key: '1338076800000', val:444693 },
  { key: '1338163200000', val:452282 },
  { key: '1338249600000', val:462189 },
  { key: '1338336000000', val:466626 }]
}";

public class itemClass
{
  public string key; // or int
  public int val;
}

public class items
{
  public itemClass[] daily;
}

items daily = (new JavascriptSerializer()).Deserialize<items>(json);
```

Then you can:

```
var itemValue = items.Where(x=>x.key=='1338163200000').Select(x=>x.val).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: There's no reason to change the JSON. C# can happily handle dictionary keys starting with numbers.

Comment: Most importantly this is not a JSON with dynamic key