# JsonConvert help reading from file

Tags: c#, json.net

I am trying to read from this json file, The problem is that I am not getting any info back, also `1357` is always changing.

This is part of the file

```
{
    "result": {
        "1357": {
            "Random": "4NUX4oFJZEHLbXH5ApeO4",
            "Random2": "Co04DEVlxkKgpou-6kej",
```

The class I am using to read it

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class ReadRandom
    {
        public static ReadRandom Fetch(string filename)
        {
            TextReader reader = new StreamReader(filename);
            string json = reader.ReadToEnd();
            reader.Close();

            ReadRandomResult AssetClassInfoResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ReadRandomResult>(json);

            return AssetClassInfoResult.result;
        }

        [JsonProperty("Random")]
        public string Random { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Random2")]
        public string Random2 { get; set; }


        protected class ReadRandomResult
        {
            public ReadRandom result { get; set; }
        }

    }
}
```

Errors from one of the answers

```
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in Newtonsoft.Json.dll
Exception thrown: 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' in Newtonsoft.Json.dll
Exception thrown: 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' in Newtonsoft.Json.dll
Exception thrown: 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' in Newtonsoft.Json.dll
Exception thrown: 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' in Newtonsoft.Json.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' in mscorlib.dll
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
```

http://pastebin.com/Hvp4CXXw

Im trying to read "icon_url"
An a few things under that.
Sorry that i didnt post it all before thought i didnt need it
When using that in the example you posted an change the key to the right one i still crash.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you've got the extra "layer" between the `result` property and the object with `Random` and `Random2`. It looks like you want something like:

```
class ReadRandomResult
{
    public Dictionary<string, ReadRandom> Result { get; set; }
}
```

Then you'd be able to use:

```
var container = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ReadRandomResult>(json);
var result = container.Result["1357"];
```

As a note, I'd strongly recommend moving your `ReadRandomResult` class outside `ReadRandom`... it's pretty unusual to have a "container" class nested *inside* the class it contains. That's likely to cause confusion.

Here's a short but complete example that works:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

using Newtonsoft.Json;

class ReadRandom
{
    [JsonProperty("Random")]
    public string Random { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Random2")]
    public string Random2 { get; set; }
}

class ReadRandomContainer
{
    [JsonProperty("Result")]
    public Dictionary<string, ReadRandom> Result { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var json = File.ReadAllText("test.json");
        var container = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ReadRandomContainer>(json);
        Console.WriteLine(container.Result["1357"].Random);
    }
}
```

Contents of `test.json`:

```
{
    "result": {
        "1357": {
            "Random": "4NUX4oFJZEHLbXH5ApeO4",
            "Random2": "Co04DEVlxkKgpou-6kej"
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
4NUX4oFJZEHLbXH5ApeO4
```

Comment: i always seem to get a crash on `DeserializeObject` when i try this

Comment: @ramafe: Well without more detail than "get a crash" it's impossible to help you any further. I suggest you produce a short but *complete* example in your question, along with the details of the crash (the full stack trace).

Comment: i posted the errors i get in my question. STill trying to work out why

Comment: @ramafe: Well without a short but complete example, we can't help you further. I've edited my answer to show a short but complete example that *does* work.

Comment: ok i think i have worked out whats going on, Your example works i get the same back as you said. i think the problem is with the bigger json file im reading. This is the start of the sting i return reading mine `"{\r\n\t\"result\": {\r\n\t\t\"1357\": {\r\n\t\t\t\"Random\":` and this is the string i get from your example `"{\r\n    \"result\": {\r\n        \"1357\": {\r\n            \"Random\":`

Comment: @ramafe: The only difference I can see there is tables, which are irrelevant. It's more likely to be something *elsewhere* in the file. Unfortunately, as you haven't given us a complete example, we can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: not sure if that could be the problem and if i need to add something else

Comment: i pasted a link to the full json the real one im trying to read.

Comment: @ramafe: Now that's too much. As the person asking the question, it's your responsibility to find a *minimal* example that demonstrates the problem. We shouldn't have to do the diagnostic work for you. In fact, I'd strongly recommend that you accept an answer on *this* question, then ask a new question with the complete example of the next problem. We've answered the question you originally asked.

Comment: well im not sure if i can shorten it down and ask a question because then again i would not be giving all the info needed.

Comment: @ramafe: Why would you *not* be giving all the info needed? You give a short example that still demonstrates the problem. Please read [mcve]

Comment: I wouldnt of thought there would be a point in me reposting because they will just say i already asked the same question.

Comment: @ramafe: But it's not the same question. That's the point - we've answered the question you asked. Now, implementing the solution, you've found a problem with that solution - because of things that *weren't* in this question. So you should ask another question which *starts* with the solution provided here, but goes on to show (with a short but complete example) why it doesn't actually work in your case. "Bait and switch" questions which constantly evolve with "Well now I've got another problem you couldn't possibly have anticipated from my initial question" aren't helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The json you posted seems invalid. The parser can't read it.

--- edit:

at minimum you need

```
{
    "result": {
        "1357": {
            "Random": "4NUX4oFJZEHLbXH5ApeO4",
            "Random2": "Co04DEVlxkKgpou-6kej"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @ramafe He wants to say "post the full JSON file".

Comment: it there a reason why it is incomplete? if it's a config file for example you can edit it. if it's from a api then contact the api developer. Because the invalid json would probably be in no one's favor.

Comment: i only posted the top part of it as in its big, i also download it from the internet, i cant change it or dont need to i just need to read a few lines from it

Answer (score 0):

You ignore the fact that you have `1357`. Assuming you have the following JSON:

```
{
    "result": {
        "1357": {
            "Random": "4NUX4oFJZEHLbXH5ApeO4",
            "Random2": "Co04DEVlxkKgpou-6kej"
        } 
    }
}
```

your `result` is not a `ReadRandom`, but a `Dictionary<string, ReadRandom>`.

This one should work:

```
public class ReadRandom
{
    public static Dictionary<string, ReadRandom> Fetch(string filename)
    {
        TextReader reader = new StreamReader(filename);
        string json = reader.ReadToEnd();
        reader.Close();

        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ReadRandomResult>(json).result;
    }

    [JsonProperty("Random")]
    public string Random { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Random2")]
    public string Random2 { get; set; }


    protected class ReadRandomResult
    {
        public Dictionary<string, ReadRandom> result { get; set; }
    }
}

// Usage example:
string random = ReadRandom.Fetch(@"C:\filename.txt")["1357"].Random;
```

Just my opinion: implementing `Fetch` within a model class isn't a very good idea. It is better to implement something like `ReadRandomParse` which will return `ReadRandomResult`.

Answer (score 0):

Check this link where the json string has dynamic keys, they are using Idictionary and then iterating over. [Deserializing JSON with dynamic keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13517792/deserializing-json-with-dynamic-keys). Then from the remaining string you can again deserialize to the object what you want