# How to deserialize a JSON list that every item has it's own node?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

So I've got a json list in this format:

```
friendships
  14349334
    following=false
    follows=false
  12323445
    following=false
    follows=false
  542545
    following=false
    follows=false
  ...
```

It's badly formatted, they are separated by user ID as you see. If it was a `List` of `Friendship` I could have a pre-defined class and use Json.NET, but now it's not possible.

How to deserialize a list that every item has it's own node?

> {"friendships": {"904667009": {"following": false, "follows": false},
>   "918386564": {"following": true, "follows": false}, "898262788":
>   {"following": false, "follows": false}}}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deserializing JSON with dynamic keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13517792/deserializing-json-with-dynamic-keys)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a dictionary should allow you to handle the ids.

```
public class Friendship {
    public bool following { get; set; }
    public bool follows { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject {
    public Dictionary<string, Friendship> Friendships friendships { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of deserializing the json using anonymous classes:

```
var json = "{ \"friendships\": { \"904667009\": { \"following\": false, \"follows\": false}, \"918386564\": { \"following\": true, \"follows\": false}, \"898262788\": { \"following\": false, \"follows\": false} } }";

var jsonParsed = new JavaScriptSerializer().DeserializeObject(json) as Dictionary<string, object>;

var friendShips = ((Dictionary<string, object>)jsonParsed["friendships"]).Select(friendShip =>
{
    var followData = (Dictionary<string, object>)friendShip.Value;

    return new
    {
        FriendShipID = friendShip.Key,
        Following = Convert.ToBoolean(followData["following"]),
        Follows = Convert.ToBoolean(followData["follows"])
    };
}).ToList();
```

You could even swap out the anonymous classes with the ones Nkosi posted

Comment: Yeah I actually use Json.NET myself :)