# How to handle value has properties in json?

Tags: c#, json

I have this Json, that I have no control over with the following structure:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }

    // TypeBlock
    //...
    // AddressBlock
    //...

    // DayBlock
    public bool exceptionalDay_2018_05_01 { get; set; }
    public bool? exceptionalDay_2018_05_05 { get; set; }
    public bool? exceptionalDay_2018_05_06 { get; set; }
    public bool? exceptionalDay_2018_05_08 { get; set; }
    public bool exceptionalDay_2018_05_10 { get; set; }
    public bool? exceptionalDay_2018_05_13 { get; set; }
    public bool? exceptionalDay_2018_05_20 { get; set; }
    public bool exceptionalDay_2018_05_21 { get; set; }
    public bool? exceptionalDay_2018_05_27 { get; set; }
}
```

The issue is simple not working day are send to me with in exceptionalDay Property.

Every time I query the working day for the month are compute and send has properties.

How to handle those property that will change every month?

And perhaps select those into a more generic type like :

```
public class RootObject
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }

    // TypeBlock
    //...
    // AddressBlock
    //...

    // DayBlock // .Where( property == true )
    public List<DateTime> exceptionalDays { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Use a `Dictionary<string, whatever>`. Show some actual JSON if you want more specific help, but first try solving it using the information in the [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13517792/deserializing-json-with-dynamic-keys).

Comment: Thanks man I was doing some Reflexion on the C# class after dinamics. this way Is more simple. Do my question need to disapear has duplicate or can it stay ?

Comment: Just let it stay, your wording can help others find that duplicate.