# Deserialize JSON to C# Objects with Childs

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization

I have a JSON string and I need some help to deserialize it. 
At the moment my result is always null.

```
var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);
// result == null
```

My JSON:

```
{"First":{"FirstData1":{"date":"2018-01-01","hint":""},
"FirstData2":{"date":"2018-01-06","hint":""}},
"Second":{"SecondData1":{"date":"2018-01-01","hint":""},
"SecondData2":{"date":"2018-01-06","hint":""}}}....
```

Only on the last Node there is actual property naming...

MyObjects

```
public class Root
{
    public IEnumerable<TempModelRoot> Value{ get; set; }
}

public class TempModelRoot
{
    [JsonProperty("Key")]
    public string Key { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Value")]
    public List<TempModelChild> Value { get; set; }
}

public class TempModelChild
{
    [JsonProperty("Key")]
    public string Key { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Value")]
    public TempModelInfo Value { get; set; }
}


public class TempModelInfo
{
    [JsonProperty("date")]
    public string date { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("hint")]
    public string hint { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Try plugging your json in [Quick type model generator](https://app.quicktype.io/#l=cs&r=json2csharp) and see how your models compare to the generated ones.

Comment: I think it's due to the dynamic keys ("First", "Second", "FirstData1", "FirstData2", etc.). You could try the suggestion of using Dictionary seen in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13517792/deserializing-json-with-dynamic-keys

Comment: Your class doesn't match the json provided. Root is not an IEnumerable for example.

Comment: @MXD good link! went straight to my favorites, thanks!

Comment: @MXD Worked for me. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you are having a mismatch between the model you are trying to deserialize to, and the actual expected model based of the json itself.

A easy way to resolve this is by using a tool such as [Quick Types Model Generator](https://app.quicktype.io/#l=cs&r=json2csharp)<sup>(unafiliated)</sup> which allows you to generate C# models based upon a provided json file.

After generation you can compare and/or replace your models with the generated models.
To spot and resolve the issue with your model.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @MX D 's answer, I want to add two more useful model generator sites, which takes JSON as an input and gives appropriate model classes.

[Json2Csahrp](http://json2csharp.com/)

[JsonUtils](https://jsonutils.com/)

Use, whenever you find difficult to generate complex model classes.