# create C# class as per JSON Structure

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, json.net, deserialization, json-deserialization

I'm working on Xamarin forms. I have created a C# class for Deserializing the JSON. But I don't know how to mention few object. Even used [this option](http://json2csharp.com/), but still getting this error:

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.NotSupportedException: Don't know about System.Collections.Generic.List` while creating table.

Here is my JSON

```
[{
    "firstName":"X", 
    "lastName":"Y", 
    "Ids":["1"],
    "specialIds":[],
    "options":{
        "isAccepting":false
    }
}, 
{   
    "firstName":"Z", 
    "lastName":"A", 
    "Ids":["11"], 
    "specialIds":[],
    "options":{
        "isAccepting":false}
    },
}]
```

Here is my C#

```
public class Provider
{
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }

    public List<string> Ids { get; set; }
    public List<string> specialIds { get; set; }
    public Options options { get; set; }
}
public class Options
{
    public bool isAccepting { get; set; }
}
```

How to assign IDs, SpecialIds and options in C#? If I use just firstname & lastname, it is working perfectly. But if I use the others, I'm getting error. 
Please help me to assign this object as per the above mentioned JSON.

Comment: Your JSON is invalid. You have mismatched quotes around `firstName`.

Comment: "while creating table" - this sounds like a problem with SQLite, not JSON.

Comment: firstName JSON typo mistake. Now I corrected.  "While creating table" - Working fine if I remove Ids, specialIds & Options. How come at that time it's working. So I don't think it's with SQLite ( my suggestion ).

Comment: You haven't posted the code that actually generates the error.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to include the full `ToString()` output of the exception including the exception type, message, complete traceback and inner exception(s), if any?

Comment: [UsefulSites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51517404/deserialize-json-to-c-sharp-objects-with-childs) - this que contains some useful points.

Answer (score 0):

Your current Json is invalid, it should look like something like this:

```
[
  {
    "firstName": "X",
    "lastName": "Y",
    "Ids": [
      "1"
    ],
    "specialIds": [],
    "options": {
      "isAccepting": false
    }
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Z",
    "lastName": "X",
    "Ids": [
      "11"
    ],
    "specialIds": [],
    "options": {
      "isAccepting": false
    }
  }
]
```

If you want a C# modal of it, it will look like this:

```
public class Provider
{
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    public IList<string> Ids { get; set; }
    public IList<string> specialIds { get; set; }
    public Options options { get; set; }
}

public class Options
{
    public bool isAccepting { get; set; }
}
```

> How to assign IDs, SpecialIds and options in C#? If I use just
>   firstname & lastname, it is working perfectly. But if I use the
>   others, I'm getting error. Please help me to assign this object as per
>   the above mentioned JSON.

Remember your not assign directly to a value, your appending a list item of strings

```
    IList<string> items = new IList<string>();
    items.add("12");
```