# Set id as Object name in model for rest api asp.net core

Tags: c#

I would like to use this address based on the model I created to make pay way ids as object names. How do I do that?
[image: Rest api response]

[image: My model by rest api response]

how solve it ?

Comment: [Does this answer your question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13517792/deserializing-json-with-dynamic-keys)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deserializing JSON with dynamic keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13517792/deserializing-json-with-dynamic-keys)