# Deserialize a JSON C#

Tags: c#

i'm first time looking at this type of JSON and seems like i need some help with that. Appreciated for any help to understand how can i get all the "history" through the foreach loop.

- "THRUSTMASTER K450 ELITE" it's a name of item, could be various so i can't use that as a class name to deserialize.
- How to break "[[" symbols to reach history data? It's might be `List<List<string>` but i haven't work with that.

Appreciated for any help, thanks.

So, the JSON is:

```
{
    "success":true,
    "currency":"CDN",
    "data":
    {
        "THRUSTMASTER K450 ELITE":
        {
            "max":289999,
            "min":3318.179,
            "average":45683.415,
            "history":
            [
                [1602685074,34000],
                [1602674793,18015.366],
                [1602522260,38660],
                [1602503464,34111.14],
                [1602448764,38650],
                [1602432437,31500.11],
                [1602295430,37990],
                [1602190139,36300],
                [1602180785,36299.99],
                [1602145104,30771.2],
                [1602139051,33410],
                [1602101107,36399.99],
                [1602099033,36399.98],
                [1601999331,36398.6],
                [1601926118,36190],
                [1601860515,31900],
                [1601838015,34240],
                [1601770655,38000],
                [1601713059,32499.98],
                [1601690337,36688],
                [1601453568,35100],
                [1601417196,36832.87],
                [1601363870,33227.49],
                [1601036808,33111.75],
                [1601032263,165900],
                [1600895746,28797.79],
                [1600682237,32150],
                [1600677885,32100],
                [1600674462,34990],
                [1600626352,34999],
                [1600531802,31999],
                [1600520135,41993.5],
                [1600475894,3318.179],
                [1600423460,30000],
                [1600408526,29249.48],
                [1600392002,32100],
                [1600343160,289999],
                [1600069790,28500.08],
                [1599961854,32353.07],
                [1599776303,35397.04],
                [1599766724,31589],
                [1599675336,31899],
                [1599658055,30000.03],
                [1599656012,30000],
                [1599579376,41500],
                [1599569405,275000],
                [1599416023,30041.12],
                [1599317567,34899],
                [1598934946,35800],
                [1598898545,32900]
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

The thread marked as a duplicate does not answer the question.

Comment: This may help with the first: [Deserializing JSON with dynamic keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13517792/deserializing-json-with-dynamic-keys)

Comment: `Thrustmasster k450 elite` can be used in a class, you will need a `[JsonProperty()]` attribute to use it

Comment: @janzen as i said it's can be various on every request but i can't change it inside of the code every time.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski still can't figure out how to use that on my example, sorry :(

Comment: @Inflactwf, with the understanding that "THRUSTMASTER K450 ELITE" is not a constant name, will the properties in this class be constant? Max. Min. Average. History.

Comment: I have edited my answer.

Comment: @CaseyCrookston nope, i just don't need other but the History.

Comment: @janzen thanks bruh will take a look all yours rn, trying to understand your examples

Comment: @Inflactwf, well.. now I can't edit my answer because this was closed as a duplicate. I don't think this IS a duplicate as this one has a much more dynamic nested object. If you want to try to edit this question, or post a new one, I can share the working sample I came up with.

Comment: @Inflactwf, I have a working sample, if you are interested

Comment: @CaseyCrookston sry bruh, its like other guys did well also so i can use them. But if you want you can post yours and i will check of course, thanks.

Comment: @Inflactwf -- just happy you have it solved! That was my only concern.

Comment: @CaseyCrookston no problem, thanks for your time and have a nice day ! :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In that structure you have an object (root), then inside another object (data) with another object inside (THRUSTMASTER K450 ELITE) and then inside you have an array of float/decimal arrays. You can acces directly using a JObject if you don't want to create all the data structure:

UPDATE: updated to be completelly dynamic

```
//Assume the JSON string is in the var "json"
var json = //...

var ob = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(json);
var historyOb = (ob["data"].Children().First() as JProperty).Value["history"];
var history = history.ToObject<float[][]>(); //Now you have a float array of arrays

//Now we can iterate it to process the data
foreach(var entry in history)
{
    var entryA = entry[0];
    var entryB = entry[1];
    //Do whatever you want with them :D
}
```

Comment: @mason Of course, because it's an string which can be replaced with any variable, that's more than enough for an example.

Comment: @mason Ok, fair enough, now it's completelly dynamic.

Comment: Totally worked well, thanks bro. I think i should learn what's there written, appreciated for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Create these classes:

```
public class ClassName    
{
    public int max { get; set; } 
    public double min { get; set; } 
    public double average { get; set; } 
    public List<List<double>> history { get; set; } 
}

public class Root    
{
    public bool success { get; set; } 
    public string currency { get; set; } 
    public Dictionary<string, ClassName> data { get; set; } 
}
```

Then make sure that the Newtonsoft nuget package is installed and `Deserialize`:

```
var values = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(jsonString);
```

Then instead of a foreach loop to get the `history` values I would recommend for loops:

```
List<double> historyValues = new List<double>{ };

for (int i = 0; i < values.data.Values.Count(); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < values.data.Values.ElementAt(i).history.Count(); j++)
    {
        historyValues.Add(values.data.Values.ElementAt(i).history[j]);
    }
}
```

The outer loop is for the entire `Deserialized` class, the inner loop will check the count of `history` to prevent `IndexOutOfRange Exception`. Then it will add that value to the new `List<double>`.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: I have edited my answer.

Comment: Excellent, that looks much better.

Comment: @janzen It says "var item in values.data.history" could not find "history" in "data" for some reason.

Comment: I'll change that.

Comment: @janzen for now it says "values.data.Values" doesn't exist.

Comment: If you `Deserialized` it into `values` then `values.data` is the `data` property from `Root`. And `values.data.Values` is specifying the `ClassName` of the `data` property. Double check what you've have named the `Deserialized` object. In case you named your variables differently.

Comment: @janzen worked well, thanks bro!