# Deserialize json Object in C# with changing keys/ value names

Tags: c#, json, serialization

So I receive a json file in the format below. Now, the issue is, I do not know how to deserialize it because it has non constant names, i.e. "1", "2", "3".
I want to use JsonConvert.DeserializeObject in C#.
I tried to have it interpreted as a tuple, did not work. It is clear to me what to do if the "1","2","3", were all just called a constant name like "stuff".

```js
{

  "questionId": , 
  "resultRecords": [
    {
      "1": {
        "RELATED_MPN": "", 
        "gool": , 
      }
    }, 
    {
      "2": {
        "RELATED_MPN": "", 
        "gool": , 

      }
    },
    {
      "3": {
        "RELATED_MPN": "", 
        "gool": , 

      }
  ], 
  "userName": ""
}
```

Comment: When you see varying keys, you can often be deserialize into a dictionary. In your case it would be `Dictionary<string, CustomClass>` where `CustomClass` has the "RELATED_MPN" and "gool" properties. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59358071/9665021) in the duplicate has details for both newtonsoft and system.text.json

Comment: @haldo yes it perfectly solves it. Thank you for your answer! Have a nice day!