# Mapping a dynamic object in C#

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

How can I map a class that has fix structures but dynamic keys?
Here goes an example:

```json
{
    "John": {
        "Id": 1,
        "FullName": "John Doe",
        "BirthYear": "1960"
    },
    "Drake": {
        "Id": 2,
        "FullName": "Drake Bell",
        "BirthYear": "1988"
    }
}
```

So I have an object with some workes, the Worker object will always be the same, but the key is different for every individual.
Is it possible to create a class that maps this object?

Comment: Sounds like a `Dictionary<string, Person>` to me.

Comment: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingCollections.htm

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59358071/9665021) in the suggested duplicate shows you how to do it in newtonsoft or system.text.json but you'd deserialize to `Dictionary<string, Person>` as mason suggested

Answer (score 0):

The most common way is to use a dictionary. Try this code

```
Dictionary<string, Person> persons = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Person>>(json);
```

you can get data this way

```
Person John = persons["John"];
```

class

```
public class Person
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FullName { get; set; }
        public string BirthYear { get; set; }
    }
```