# How to get a value from JSON object with approximate key

Tags: c#, json

I have below JSON file under service map, The Key values are not fixed

```
{
"ServiceMap": {
    "rackAC1": {
        "Env": "Public",
        "Center": "north"
    },
    "rackD1": {
        "Env": "Public",
        "Center": "south"
    },
    "rackD2": {
        "Env": "Public",
        "Center": "North-south"
    },
    "rackD3": {
        "Env": "Public",
        "Center": "south"
    },
    ...,
    "rackD1000": {
        "Env": "Public",
        "Center": "south"
    },
    "rackBO": {
        "Env": "Public",
        "Center": "East"
    },
    "rackB1": {
        "Env": "Public",
        "Center": "West"
    }
}
```

}
I want to extract the key values from rackD1 to rackD1000 whose center is south using linq.
is it possible to extract the key value like JsonContent["serviceMap"][rackD1*]

Comment: What JSON library are you using? The default `System.Text.Json` or `Newtonsoft.Json`?

Comment: Please format your JSON with proper indentation so it's easier to read for us.

Comment: rackAC1 etc is a string key of a dictionary. It will be easier to access.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deserializing JSON with dynamic keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13517792/deserializing-json-with-dynamic-keys)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you dont need any classes to get list of keys

```
    List<string> keys = ((JObject)JObject.Parse(json)["ServiceMap"]).Properties()
    .Where(p => p.Name.Contains("rackD") 
                  && ((string)p.Value["Center"]).ToLower() == "south")
    .Select(p => p.Name)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just deserialize it to proper class structure and use LINQ on the results.

```
public class Root
{
    // use dictionary to represent dynamic property names
    public Dictionary<string, ServiceMap> ServiceMap { get; set; } 
}

public class ServiceMap
{
    public string Env { get; set; } // can be excluded if not needed
    public string Center { get; set; }
}
```

And filter results:

```cs
var root = ... ; // deserialized root
var result = root.ServiceMap
   .Where(kvp => kvp.Value.Center == "south") // or kvp.Value.Center.Equals("south", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) for case-insensitive
   .Select(kvp => kvp.Key) // keys like "rackD1", ...
   .ToList();
```

Comment: var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(jsonContent["servermap"].ToString()); after deserialize I am getting root.ServiceMap Null value

Comment: @Sravani just read the whole response as string.

Comment: whole response means the enter Jsoncontent as a string? I have tried that but still root.ServiceMap is Null

Comment: @Sravani can you please post the whole json structure? Is the posted json only part of the response (i.e. it is is part of several nested object)?

Comment: servermap is the root node JObject jsonContent = JsonUtilities.ReadJson(content);  jsonContent[servermap] will give the entire content what I have posted

Comment: @Sravani was not able to [reproduce](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lMv5YQ)